# Problem scraping title, price and date from a site using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Hi guuys Im trying to scrape some information about a shoe of zalando and save the price, the title, the day and the hour in differents variables using Seleinum webdriver.This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/')

#Get the data of product 1 (If I change the /div/div[1]/div and I choose another number, it will get ther data of other shoe)

product_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="release-calendar"]/div/div[1]/div')

element_text = product_1.text


print(element_text)
```

When I print the element_text of the next code I get a lot of information about the product. I want to safe this in diferent variables so I tried one thing (keep reading)

109,95 €
Nike Sportswear
WMNS DUNK LOW CZ
10 de noviembre de 2022, 8:15
Recordármelo

So the thing is that after this little code works, I tried to split the data  adding this code to then safe the diferent types of data in diferent variables, but I had a problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/')

#Select product 1 

product_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="release-calendar"]/div/div[1]/div')

element_text = product_1.text

#Split the data 
element_text_split = element_text.split()  

#Price 1 --> Result=109.95

price_1 =element_text_split[0]
print(price_1)
#Result=109,95

#Title 1 --> Result=€

title_1 =element_text_split[1]
print(title_1)
```

The result of this 2 prints are:
"109.95"
and "€"

I was thinking that the  element_text_split[1] was Nike Sportswear but no, its the € sign because Im splitting the data by the spaces between them.

This is a big problem if I want to get the title of the shoe because the names doesnt have the sames spaces between them like : Nike Dunk Low Cz or  Air Jordan One Mid 1

How can I resolve this problem??Thaanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could be searching for something like this?

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# We create the driver
DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

# We maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()

# We navigate to the url
url='https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/'
driver.get(url)

# We save a list of elements that are products (search for that xpath in the page and you will see what kind of element it is)
products = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='release-calendar']//div[contains(@data-cid,'cid')]")))

# We make a loop for that list and for each of then we take the price, the brand, the model and the date.
for i, product in enumerate(products):
    price = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']/div[2]"))).text
    brand = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']/div[3]"))).text
    model = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']/div[4]"))).text
    date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']/div[5]"))).text
    url = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']//a"))).get_attribute("href")
    image = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-cid='cid{i+1}']//img"))).get_attribute("src")
    print(f"""{price}
{brand}
{model}
{date}
{url}
{image}
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to take a look at the variable, element_text, for *many* different products, and decide a different way to split the text - the [split method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) can take in a smaller string to split the longer string by.

If that doesnt work, you can also iterate through the element_text_split variable (which is just a list of strings), and break up that list of strings by looking for certain smaller strings or by using [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

For example, to find the prices, you could look for numbers, a period, then numbers again. I'm assuming the name of the product is either before or after. Gl!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the required data powerful way using selenium with bs4

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

d = []
driver.get('https://www.zalando.es/release-calendar/zapatillas-mujer/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
price= [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('.Wqd6Qu + div')]
#print(price)
title= [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('.Wqd6Qu + div + div + div')]
#print(title)

date = [x.get_text(strip=True).split(',')[0] for x in soup.select('.Wqd6Qu + div + div + div + div')]
#print(date)


hour = [x.get_text(strip=True).split(',')[1] for x in soup.select('.Wqd6Qu + div + div + div + div')]
#print(hour)


cols = ['title', 'price', 'date', 'hour']
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(title,price,date,hour)), columns=cols)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                   title     price             date           hour
0       WMNS DUNK LOW CZ  109,95 €  10 de noviembre de 2022   14:15
1    HYPERTURF ADVENTURE  139,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
2       W AIR MAX 95 ESS  189,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
3           CITY CLASSIC  119,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
4           CITY CLASSIC  119,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
5         WMNS AIR 1 MID  129,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:15
6   DUNK LOW NEXT NATURE  109,95 €  11 de noviembre de 2022   14:15
7            CROSS WOMEN  295,00 €  14 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
8            CROSS WOMEN  295,00 €  14 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
9            CROSS WOMEN  295,00 €  14 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
10           W DUNK HIGH  119,95 €  14 de noviembre de 2022   14:15
11                 MT410   99,95 €  16 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
12                 MT410   99,95 €  16 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
13                 MT410   99,95 €  16 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
14                 MT410   99,95 €  16 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
15                 MT410   94,95 €  16 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
16                 WL574  109,95 €  18 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
17                 WS327  119,95 €  18 de noviembre de 2022   14:00
```